# UWP - Read a file and be able to cancel the playback/opening

Tags: c#, uwp

Note : I use a translation app. Sorry if it's not always very understandable.

I'm developing a UWP application, and I'm having a problem with managing a file type, the CBZ extension. 
Some files open without a problem, others the file never opens and blocks the Task.

Here's the code I use :

```
Task loadEbookTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Stream streamEbook = WindowsRuntimeStorageExtensions.OpenStreamForReadAsync(ebookFile).Result;

    Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
    Content = new ZipArchive(streamEbook, ZipArchiveMode.Read, false);

        // Pour charque archive, prendre que des extensions valident.
        foreach (var file in Content.Entries)
    {
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.Name).ToLower();
        bool isFileExtensionOk = EbooksManager.AvailableExtensionsImage.Contains(extension);

        if (isFileExtensionOk)
        {
            ArchivesExploitable.Add(file);
        }
    }

    TotalPage = Convert.ToUInt32(ArchivesExploitable.Count());
});

if (loadEbookTask.Wait(4000))
{
    EbookCbz.LoadEbook = EbookLoad.Ok;
}
else
{
    EbookCbz.LoadEbook = EbookLoad.Timeout;
}
```

It's looping on :

```
Stream streamEbook = WindowsRuntimeStorageExtensions.OpenStreamForReadAsync(ebookFile).Result;
```

In Visual Studio, memory doesn't go up any more, but the Garbage Collector keeps being called.
With the Task.Wait(4000), it does not stop the Task, so it does not stop turning in background.
And if I open another file, a new task is created, and will turn into a background task.

My question is:
- Is there a method that open a file, and that it is possible to cancel if it exceeds a certain time.

Comment: Hello, I noticed that you asked the [same question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/25873/uwp-read-a-file-and-be-able-to-cancel-the-playback.html) in Microsoft Q&A and I have already answered you there. If you have questions about the answer, you can reply there.

Comment: I test this in the day thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is this method that is problematic.

```
Stream streamEbook = WindowsRuntimeStorageExtensions.OpenStreamForReadAsync(ebookFsile).Result;
```

I change my code to :

```
byte[] buffer = await ebookFile.ReadBytesAsync();
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);

Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
Content = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Read, false);
```

It's fast and if the file is corrupted, there's an exception. It's no longer in memory.
Thanks for your help, I learned a new concept.

Comment: Hello, glad you found a solution, you can mark your answer, this will help more people who encounter the same problem.